# Hazelcast set(k, v) vs EntryProcessor

Tags: hazelcast

I have a question regarding `EntryProcessor`. If I already have a value that I just want to put back in the map.

Would there be any difference in performance using:

```
map.set(key, value);
```

Compared to using EntryProcessor:

```
Value value = new Value();

map.executeOnKey(key, entry -> entry.setValue(value));
```

FYI I use sync backups.

Answer (score 0):

`map.set()` is a higher level API to update the whole value. It saves the cost of deploying the entry processor class (lambda in the example) to the cluster.

`EntryProcessor` is better choice if you want to update a small part of larger object (e.g. just a first name for a large customer object).

Comment: Thanks for verifying. That was my understanding also.